# nginx not redirecting to https

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

I am following the instructions on [this page](https://www.charlesbordet.com/en/guide-shiny-aws/#6-extra-secure-your-app-with-https) to setup an R Shiny server on a DigitalOcean droplet.

What I would like to have:

1. A Shiny server running on shiny.domain.com
2. Automatic redirect from shiny.domain.com to https://shiny.domain.com
3. Automatic redirect from http://shiny.domain.com to https://shiny.domain.com

At the moment 1 and 2 work, but 3 does not.
If I visit https first then http gets redirected to https, but if I use http the first time (e.g. in an incognito window) I get Nginx welcome page instead.

My Nginx configuration is as follows (Shiny server listens to 3838, so a reverse proxy is setup to automatically redirect traffic, so I don't have to type :3838 every time, as explained in the link above)

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

# redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate <path to certificate>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/snippets/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers xxxxxx
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;

    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    ssl_trusted_certificate <path to chain.pem>

    server_name shiny.domain.com;  

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 20d;
        proxy_buffering off;
        }
    }
```

I am extremely new to nginx, so I would appreciate some help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `server` block for `http` is missing `server_name`. This means nginx will use the `default_server` for these requests, which will display the welcome page.

Replace your first block with:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name shiny.example.com;

    return 301 https://shiny.example.com;
}
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! I was expecting something really complex, instead it was very easy!